# Styling a single word inside a <Text /> element react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm looking for a way to style a single word (or multiple words) which is inside a `<Text>` with other words.

Say styling a word in a sentence that is inside `<Text>`.

Something like this.

"The words i *put inside* a sentence" (**i.e** The italics)

I'm currently doing something like

`<Text>The words i </Text> <Text style={...}> style inside </Text> <Text> a sentence </Text>`

But unfortunately every `<Text />` element i add makes a newline effect so it ends up in multiple lines.

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using Text as a container like the following example

```
<Text>
  <Text>The words i </Text>
  <Text style={...}> style inside </Text>
  <Text> a sentence </Text>
</Text>
```